# Cannot send HTML email via PHP

Tags: php, html-email

I am trying to sending an HTML email upon an order submission , hence at first I read last inserted row in database

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `$db`.`pre_order` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1;";
    $result = mysql_query($sql2, $dbcon);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $id= $row['id'];
    $name=$row['name'];
    $address=$row['delivery_location'];
    $mobile =$row['mobile'];
    $email= $row['email'];
    $to = $email;
    $from = "info@sundoriagro.com"; 
    $subject = "Thanks You message";    

    $message = '

                <html>
                    <head>
                        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                        <title>Sundori Honey</title>
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/table.css" type="text/css">
                    </head>
                    <body style="width:600px;">
                        <div class="begining">  
                            <p>
                                Dear <span> <?php echo $name?></span> <br/>

                Thank you for your booking. We are pleased to confirm detail as follows:

                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <table border="1" style="width:80% ;margin: auto;">

                            <tr>
                                <td>Confirmation Number: </td>
                                <td> <?php echo $id;?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Client’s Name & Contact No:</td>
                                <td><?php echo $name .' and ' .$mobile;?></td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td> Contact Address:</td>
                                <td><?php echo $address;?></td>
                            </tr>




                        </table>
                            <div class="begining">  
                            <p>

    Thanks
                            Sincerely,<br/><br/>

                Johm<br/><br/>
                Manager – Marketing & Sales<br/>
                </p>
                        </div>
                    </body>

                </html>
                '; /*---end of HTML msg--*/


    $headers  = "From: $from\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Upon form submission , I do get a msg , but the problem is , it only show  something like this

[image]

The mail doesn't show any value which I have read from database and It show only two rows of the table , Even it doesn't show the footer text which is located below table .

Comment: The sql query is right , I have printed out it in HTML page . It works exactly as I want to .

Comment: Also, for large portion of code, consider [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Answer (score 3):

The values of variables will not be parsed under single quotes !

You have this `$message` variable ..

```
 $message = '....... your content .....';
```

Enclose that under double quotes like this..

```
$message = " ..... your content ......';
```

Otherwise , you could make use a [`HEREDOC`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax.

### The **`HEREDOC`** Syntax for your `$message` variable.

```
$message=<<<HTMLMAIL

.... your content..........
// more content....
HTMLMAIL;
```

Paste all the content inside your `$message` variable and put it under the `HEREDOC`

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about heredoc.

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of error in you code. You have used `<?php echo  ?>` tags at unwanted places

you dont want to specify  inside php again. You are just storing those html content as a string. so remove it from `$message` like

change this

`Dear <span> <?php echo $name?></span> <br/>`

to

```
Dear <span>  $name</span> <br/>
```

also while using doubles dont forget change the  quotes in html attributes to single quotes

so change whole $message to this

```
$message = "

                <html>
                    <head>
                        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
                        <title>Sundori Honey</title>
                        <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/table.css' type='text/css'>
                    </head>
                    <body style='width:600px;'>
                        <div class='begining'>  
                            <p>
                                Dear <span>$name</span> <br/>

                Thank you for your booking. We are pleased to confirm detail as follows:

                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <table border='1' style='width:80% ;margin: auto;'>

                            <tr>
                                <td>Confirmation Number: </td>
                                <td> $id</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Client’s Name & Contact No:</td>
                                <td> $name  and $mobile </td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td> Contact Address:</td>
                                <td> $address </td>
                            </tr>




                        </table>
                            <div class='begining'>  
                            <p>

    Thanks
                            Sincerely,<br/><br/>

                Johm<br/><br/>
                Manager – Marketing & Sales<br/>
                </p>
                        </div>
                    </body>

                </html>
                ";
```

Answer (score 0):

-Does not use the php tags in php

-You must concatenate "name" and "adresse" with the point (.)

Like this

```
  <tr>
       <td>Client’s Name & Contact No:</td>
         <td>'.$name .' and ' .$mobile.'</td>
       </tr><tr>
       <td> Contact Address:</td>
       <td>'.$address.'</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$message = '

        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <title>Sundori Honey</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/table.css" type="text/css">
            </head>
            <body style="width:600px;">
                <div class="begining">  
                    <p>
                        Dear <span>' . $name . '</span> <br/>

        Thank you for your booking. We are pleased to confirm detail as follows:

                    </p>
                </div>
                <table border="1" style="width:80% ;margin: auto;">

                    <tr>
                        <td>Confirmation Number: </td>
                        <td>' . $id . '</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Client’s Name & Contact No:</td>
                        <td>' . $name .' and ' . $mobile . '</td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td> Contact Address:</td>
                        <td>' . $address . '</td>
                    </tr>




                </table>
                    <div class="begining">  
                    <p>Thanks
                    Sincerely,<br/><br/>

        Johm<br/><br/>
        Manager – Marketing & Sales<br/>
        </p>
                </div>
            </body>

        </html>
        ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your $message value.

```
$message = '

                <html>
                    <head>
                        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                        <title>Sundori Honey</title>
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/table.css" type="text/css">
                    </head>
                    <body style="width:600px;">
                        <div class="begining">  
                            <p>
                                Dear <span>'.$name.'</span> <br/>

                Thank you for your booking. We are pleased to confirm detail as follows:

                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <table border="1" style="width:80% ;margin: auto;">

                            <tr>
                                <td>Confirmation Number: </td>
                                <td>'. $id.'</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Client’s Name & Contact No:</td>
                                <td>'. $name .' and ' .$mobile .'</td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td> Contact Address:</td>
                                <td>'. $address .'</td>
                            </tr>




                        </table>
                            <div class="begining">  
                            <p>

    Thanks
                            Sincerely,<br/><br/>

                Johm<br/><br/>
                Manager – Marketing & Sales<br/>
                </p>
                        </div>
                    </body>

                </html>
                ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for $message variable

```
$message = '<html>
                <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                    <title>Sundori Honey</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/table.css" type="text/css">
                </head>
                <body style="width:600px;">
                    <div class="begining">  
                        <p>
                            Dear <span>'.$name.'</span> <br/>

            Thank you for your booking. We are pleased to confirm detail as follows:

                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <table border="1" style="width:80% ;margin: auto;">

                        <tr>
                            <td>Confirmation Number: </td>
                            <td>'.$id.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Client’s Name & Contact No:</td>
                            <td>'.$name .' and ' .$mobile.'</td>
                        </tr><tr>
                            <td> Contact Address:</td>
                            <td>'.$address.'</td>
                        </tr>




                    </table>
                        <div class="begining">  
                        <p>

Thanks
                        Sincerely,<br/><br/>

            Johm<br/><br/>
            Manager – Marketing & Sales<br/>
            </p>
                    </div>
                </body>

            </html>';
```